# How To Design The Layers in Azure Service Fabric

Tags: azure, architecture, microservices, azure-service-fabric

I have been assigned to think of a layered microservices architecture for Azure Service Fabric. But my experience mostly been on monolithic architectures I can't come up with a specific solution.

What I have thought as of now is like...

**Data Layer -** This is where all the Code First entities resides along with DBContext.

**Business Layer -** This is where all the Service Managers would be performing and enforcing the Business Logic i.e. UserManager (IUserManager), OrderManager (IOrderManager), InvoiceManager (IInvoiceManager) etc.

**WebAPI (Self Hoted Inside Service Fabric) -** Although this WebAPI is inside Service Fabric but does nothing except to receive the request and call respectic Services under Service Fabric. WebAPI Layer would also do any Authentication and Authorization (ASP.NET Identity) before passing on the call to other services.

**Service Fabric Services -** UserService, OrderService, InvoiceService. These services are invoked from WebAPI Layer and DI the Business Layer (IUserManager, IOrderManager, IInvoiceManager) to perform it's operation.

Do you think this is okay to proceed with?

One theoretical issue though, while reading up for several microservices architecture resources, I found that, all of them suggests to have Business Logic inside the service so that the specific service can be scaled independently. So I believe, I'm violating the basic aspect of microservices.

I'm doing this because, the customer requirement is to use this Business Layer across several projects, such as Batch Jobs (Azure Web Jobs), Backend Dashboard for Internal Employees (ASP.NET MVC) etc. So If I don't keep the Business Layer same, I have to write the same Business Logic again for Web Jobs and Backend Dashboard which I feel is not a good idea. As a simple change in Business Logic would require change in code at several places then.

One more concern is, in that case, I have to go with Service to Service communication for ACID transactions. Such as, while creating an Order, a Order and Invoice both must be created. So in that case, I thought of using Event Driven programming i.e. Order Service will emit an event which the Invoice Service can subscribe to, to create Invoice on creation of Order. But the complications are if the Invoice Service fails to create invoice, it can either keep trying do that infinitely (which is a bad idea I think), or emit another event to Order Service to subscribe and roll back the order. There can be lots of confusion with this.

Also, I must mention that, we are using a Single Database as of now.

So my questions are...

1. What issue do you see with my approach? Is it okay?
2. If not, please suggest me a better approach. You can guide me to some resources for implementation details or conceptual details too.

**NOTE :** The requirement of client is, they can scale specific module in need. Such as, UserService might not be used much as there won't be many signups daily or change in User Profile, but OrderService can be scaled along as there can be lots of Orders coming in daily.

I'll be glad to learn. As this is my first chance of getting my hands on designing a microservices architecture.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why does the customer want to use Service Fabric and a microservices archtecture when it at the same time sounds like there are *other* parts of the solution (webjobs etc) that will not be a part of thar architecture but rather live in it's own ecosystem (yet share logic)? I think it would be good for you to first understand the underlying requirements that should guide the architecture. What is most imortant?

- Scalability? Flexibility?
- Development and deployment? Maintinability?
- Modularity in ability to compose new solutions based on autonomous microservices?

The list could go on. Until you figure this out there is really no point in designing further as you don't know *what you are designing for*...

As for sharing business logic with webjobs, there is nothing preventing you from sharing code packages containing the same BL, it doesn't have to be a shared service and it doesn't mean that it has to be packaged the same way in relation to its interface or persistance. Another thing to consider is, why do you wan't to run webjobs when you can build similar functionality in SF services?

Comment: By WebJobs are I meant scheduled (cron) jobs, kind of like jobs running every week / every fortnight to do some tasks to generate some reports. The customer is currently using monolithic architecture only but they are having serious problem with scaling. Like as I said above, there may not be lots of Signups every day but there can be lots of Orders coming in also say Shipping happens weekly. So here UserManagementService and ShippingService need not to be scaled but OrderService should be highly scaled. Isn't this requirement fit into Microservice architecture?

Comment: I agree that you need to get a better understanding of your domain because that's the way you be able to identify the seams/boundaries that will eventually be a candidate for a microservice. Build an adaptable, loosely coupled and testable system using some guiding principles - Agile principles, SOLID principles